# while scraping large urls i am always getting ban by using simple_html_dom php

Tags: php, web-scraping, web-crawler, simple-html-dom

i am scraping data from a website by using simple_html_dom i need to **scrape** 11,000 URL but after 200 or 250 request i am always getting ban how i can do it easily

i make some sleep call as 3,4,5 etc seconds
using user-agent
using proxy
i already optimized script

```
$url = "https://www.example.org?id=dynamic_id";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$options = array(
"http"=>array(
    "header"=>"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.102011-10-16 20:23:10\r\n" // i.e. An iPad
)
```

);

```
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$html = file_get_html($url, false, $context);
<--Scraping Code is here-->
```

I also tried proxy.
$context = array('http' => array('proxy' => "tcp://$proxies_array",'request_fulluri' => true,),);

How i can do it without getting ban. i already search lots of related things on google but failed to find out the things please help me if someone know about this.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like there is config on the remote web server that blocks requests, if there is X amount of requests in X time period from the same IP.

there is obviously nothing you can do to change the setting on the remote server, so your have to configure your app to try to work within the confines of the settings of the remote server.

without knowing what the settings are that going to be difficult

you could use sleep() https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php within your code to slow down your requests.

or you could have your script terminate after X requests then start again on a schedule X minutes later, and play with the X values until it works.

It might be better to use a 3rd party webcrawler/scraper and download all the web pages to your server and then access them locally. some of the scraper tools out there allow you to configure scrape speeds and delays.